# how to dynamic know the type is dictionary or list in python(django template)?

Tags: python, django, reflection, dynamic-typing

I just have django python code, for filter template

```
@register.filter("dict")
def dict(dict, key):
    if(dict and (key in dict)):
        return dict[key]
    else:
        return None
```

I invoke in html file:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Mon</th></tr>
        {% for item in COMP|hash:"ITEMS"|hash:"roster" %}
          {{item|dict:"Roster"}}
        {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

they dict is the dictionary object. but when I run it. 
It show me error:

```
argument of type 'Roster' is not iterable
```

I think the problem is the dict object in template is regarding as list, so it would be not iterable. how to make the python know the object is the dictionary not list?

Comment: `dict` is built in type, please use other names for variables, and functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't what you think it is. Python knows exactly what type the object is; you don't need to tell it whether you're working with a list or a dict. I don't know enough about Django to tell what the stuff in the HTML is doing, but the error message seems to indicate that you're passing in something that is neither a list nor a dict. You're actually working with something of type `Roster`. Figure out why that's happening, and you'll figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that you should use another name for the dictionary; 
You can try the following:

```
isinstance(yourDict, dict)
```